# Should I use more than one Action Mailer in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I have successfully implemented a 'SpkrMailer' in my rails application. I have an email I want to send when a 'Msg' is created by a 'Spkr'. Should I `rails g` a new mailer or should I put a new function in my SpkrMailer?

Thank you, and sorry if this question is a bit basic, I just don't know good rails conventions.

Comment: Is the new email similar/related to an existing one? Put it in the same mailer. It's different? Create a new mailer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It basically does not make a difference that you put all mailers in one file or make a separate file for each function but the convention for mailers is that you group them by a model or at least one process if there are too many functions for a single model.

In your case, I guess it will be best to group spkr-related mails in the file called spkr_mailer.rb and name the functions related to what happened like ‘created_msg’.